# Stream in orElse of optional

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I am trying to use a `Stream` in `orElse` and having difficulty in understanding the error.

```
collectorConfiguration = Optional.ofNullable(recapPlacement.getAttId())
    .map(attId -> Optional.ofNullable(processorEngine.buildFrimFromAttId(attId))
         .orElseThrow( () -> new OmegaException("UnableToFirmByAttId", recapPlacement.getAttId())))
    .orElse( () -> Optional.ofNullable(collectorConfigurations.stream() //getting error here
        .filter(cc -> recapPlacement.getPnetCode().equals(cc.getPnetCode()))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .findFirst())
        .orElseThrow( () -> new OmegaException("CollectorCouldNotMapForPnetCode", recapPlacement.getPnetCode()))
    );
```

Overall in the above code I am trying to

1. get `collectorConfig` if `attId` is not null
2. if `attId` is not null and `collectorConfig` not found for that `attId` then I am throwing exception
3. if `attId` is null then I am using `pnet` code to get `collectConfig` by streaming `collectConfigurations` list
4. if `collectConfig` is not found for `pnetCode` then I am throwing exception

It is giving a compilation error '`Target type of a lambda expression must be an interface`' in the `orElse` block.

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: Target type of a lambda expression must be an interface

Comment: Getting complex stream pipelines to compile can be tricky. There are some generally useful problem-solving techniques: 1) Add parameter types to all lambdas: `(ArgType arg) -> ...`. 2) Add explicit type parameter to methods: `<ArgType>.orElse(...)`. 3) Extract whole lambdas to local variables. The locals often look like this: `Function<Arg1, Arg2> = ...`, which makes it easy to set explicit type arguments. Applying these techniques often gives a more precise compilation error and help you find the problem. When the problem is fixed the helper types and variables can be removed.

Comment: What are the variables used in the code?

Comment: I'd recommend using a plain old if-else test on the result of `recapPlacement.getAttId()`. The `Stream` is fine, but the way you use `Optional` here violates its API notes, and the advice of its author. See [The Mother of All Bikesheds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej0sss6cq14&feature=youtu.be&t=5m40s) for some ways to make your code readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to replace

```
.orElse( () -> Optional.ofNullable(collectorConfigurations.stream() //getting error here
```

with [`Optional.orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet(java.util.function.Supplier)) which expects a `Supplier` as :

```
.orElseGet( () -> Optional.ofNullable(collectorConfigurations.stream() ...
```

---

In addition to the above, you shouldn't need the `Optional.ofNullable` in the supplier

```
.orElseGet( () -> collectorConfigurations.stream()
    .filter(cc -> recapPlacement.getPnetCode().equals(cc.getPnetCode()))
    .filter(Objects::nonNull) //non-null filtered
    .findFirst()) // optional
    .orElseThrow( () -> new OmegaException("CollectorCouldNotMapForPnet...
```

Comment: .OrElseGet() expecting a collector configuration but as I am using Optional() on it, it is throwing bad return type compilation error

Comment: Make sure you use the `() ->` as part of your `.orElseGet(()->...)`.

Comment: I am sure using it

Comment: Yeah that was a mistake. I thought I need optional to throw exception

Answer (score 1):

`orElse` takes a regular value, not anything that could be represented by a lambda. Simply removing the `() ->` should help. Alternatively, you might have meant to call `orElseGet`

Comment: If I remove '() ->' then it will be Optional() which doesn't excepted by orElse

Comment: @arjun OK; we don't have enough code to infer the types expected here, but the entire wrapping in optionals seems unnecessary. Why do you wrap the result of a `stream()` call in optional? That will never return null.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. I added it so that I can throw exception on that Optional().orElseThrow

Comment: Yeah that was the mistake. I thought I need optional to throw exception